# Using email templates

Tags: apex, email-template, massemailmessage, visualforce-template

I want a email template which will have text like this

Dear {contact.Name}

Thanks for approaching us for product {SR.product.Name}. we have reviewed your request and would like to correspond with you using {contact.Phone} .

SR is a custom object here.

Thanks,
{user.Name}
{user.title}
{user.Department}

i want to call this template using a custom controller means these is a button on a VF page . on clicking this, it will call this template and send a email to some email address.

My question here is which email template i should use here (custom or VF template) and how to pass all these objects (Contact,SR,User) data to that template.

Any help regarding this would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you are using code (Messaging.singleEmailMessage) to send the email using the template just use an HTML / Plain text email template and set the targetObjectID to the contact and the whatID to the SR record.

Comment: Please note that the limit for single email messages is 2000 per day.

Comment: and what about user ?? how will I send the user id?

Comment: @SachinKadian Use the global variable `$User` in your template to access values from the running user

Answer (score 0):

For your instance
you need a vf template to be created.
a page for your buttons logic and a controller. Your controller should contain Messaging.SingleEmailMessage().

your template should look like this>
Dear {!relatedTo.Contact.Name}
{!relatedTo.SR.Product.Name} and Thanks  {!recipient.User.Name} {!recipient.User.Name}

Hope This answers your question.